# API Gateway CDK proxy request query parameters in segments

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have my CDK in python and i am forwarding an HTTP call to another service.
Using my CDK below i managed to do it like:

```
        integration_options = _apigateway.IntegrationOptions(
            request_parameters={
                'integration.request.querystring.hw': 'method.request.path.hw',
                'integration.request.querystring.ob': 'method.request.path.ob',
                'integration.request.querystring.v': 'method.request.path.v',
                'integration.request.querystring.o': 'method.request.path.o'
            }
        )
        f_endpoint = "/endpoint"
        config_http_integration = _apigateway.HttpIntegration(
            f"https://{url}{f_endpoint}",
            http_method="GET",
            options=integration_options,
            proxy=True
        )
        resource = api_v.add_resource(f_api_name)

        hw_resource = resource.add_resource("{hw}")
        o_resource = hw_resource.add_resource("{ob}")
        ob_version = o_resource.add_resource("{v}")
        ob_version.add_resource("{o}").add_method(
            "GET",
            config_http_integration,
            request_parameters={
                'method.request.path.hw': True,
                'method.request.path.ob': True,
                'method.request.path.v': True,
                'method.request.path.o': True
            },
        )
```

which transforms the HTTP call
`http://gateway_endpoint/123/321/999/666`
to the proxy with query parameters
`http://.../endpoint?hw=123&ob=321&o=999&v=666`

but i need to have the query parameters in segments without names like below:
`http://.../endpoint/123/321/999/666`

Any idea how to forward the request having the query parameters as received in segments as the example?

Answer (score 0):

Found my way out by changing the
`integration.request.querystring.hw` to `integration.request.path.hw` for all parameters and then the mapping to the URL in the HttpIntegration like below
`f"https://{url}{f_endpoint}" + "{hw}/{to}/{v}/{o}"`